# continously loading data from servlet and displaying it in a JSP page

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a large amount of data from a database that i have to manipulate (Some string manipulations) first and then load to a JSP page. I am planing on manipulating the data from a class. A servlet will get the result of this class and forward it to the JSP page.

I believe the .load() method in Jquery allows me to load data from a servlet(using PrintWriter) and display it in a HTML div tag. I want the page to continuously load this data from a servlet. Is this possible and is my approach correct. If not please let me know the correct approach.

Thanks in advance and forgive me if my question is too silly. I have no experience in web design especially scripting.

Comment: you need to research a push solution... check the cometd.org project, this will be a start for you

Comment: Hi thanks for directing me there @fmodos,... m working on it,..